# Is it bad practice to store a foreign key like user_id in all related model tables even if some of those models are children of related models?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, foreign-keys, relational-database

We have 3 models: `Users` which can have `Orders` which can have a `Transaction` (like a credit card transaction).

Does it make sense to store the user_id on transactions or is that considered bad practice because of duplication of data? Regardless of whether transactions are always read in the context of an order (as in, in our fictional app we can never just see all the previous transactions, just all previous orders with their transaction). Are there any issues that might arise in the future? I'm not worried about database size (especially if this is just 1 integer column) but am thinking about data and code complexity.

We could have

```
Model 1: Users
- has many Orders

Model 2: Orders
- belongs to Users
- has many Transactions

Model 3: Transactions
- belongs to Orders
```

or we could have

```
Model 1: Users
- has many Orders
- has many transactions

Model 2: Orders
- belongs to Users
- has many Transactions

Model 3: Transactions
- belongs to Orders
- belongs to Users
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is the standard way of doing it. Use that unless there is a good reason not to.

The problem with the second one is that it adds complexity to your code, and there is a chance that data may become inconsistent.

The benefit of the second way is that it is faster to get all transactions belonging to a user (assuming you have an index)

Adding the index will, however,  make inserts slower.

Comment: Ok thanks! That being said, what is the “complexity” that the second option? Just 1 relation and 2 foreign keys seems fairly simple no?